# Patch command not working - can't find file to patch

Tags: linux, docker, patch

I'm unable to apply the following patch from github into my docker container. I get the error `can't find file`.

https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/ManageIQ/manageiq-providers-ansible_tower/pull/267.patch

```
root@0fec7605d8b9 manageiq-providers-ansible_tower-d5ec9817e49c]# patch < 267.patch
can't find file to patch at input line 16
Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|From 36f36d6a9985d8df27ae35cbe13bf47f16309a69 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
|From: Adam Grare <adam@grare.com>
|Date: Thu, 14 Oct 2021 10:55:39 -0400
|Subject: [PATCH 1/3] Fix merge_extra_vars with nil variables
|
|---
| .../ansible_tower/automation_manager/configuration_script.rb  | 2 +-
| .../automation_manager/configuration_workflow.rb              | 2 +-
| .../providers/ansible_tower/automation_manager/job.rb         | 4 ++--
| 3 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)
|
|diff --git a/app/models/manageiq/providers/ansible_tower/automation_manager/configuration_script.rb b/app/models/manageiq/providers/ansible_tower/automation_manager/configuration_script.rb
|index d133a97..83bad07 100644
|--- a/app/models/manageiq/providers/ansible_tower/automation_manager/configuration_script.rb
|+++ b/app/models/manageiq/providers/ansible_tower/automation_manager/configuration_script.rb
--------------------------
File to patch: q
q: No such file or directory
Skip this patch? [y] ^C
```

The files are inside the following directory

```
/opt/manageiq/manageiq-gemset/bundler/gems/manageiq-providers-ansible_tower-d5ec9817e49c
```

I'm trying to apply patch from within this directory. All the files are inside the app directory.

```
[root@0fec7605d8b9 manageiq-providers-ansible_tower-d5ec9817e49c]# ls -l
total 92
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20923 Dec 18 09:28 267.patch
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root  4096 Nov 29 01:44 app
drwxrwxr-x 3 root root  4096 Nov 29 01:44 bin
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 29 01:44 bundler.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5734 Jul 13 18:25 CHANGELOG.md
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 29 01:44 config
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   603 Jul 13 18:25 Gemfile
drwxrwxr-x 5 root root  4096 Nov 29 01:44 lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11358 Jul 13 18:25 LICENSE.txt
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 29 01:44 locale
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6630 Jul 13 18:25 manageiq-providers-ansible_tower.gemspec
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   339 Jul 13 18:25 Rakefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1735 Jul 13 18:25 README.md
```

Comment: Please start with the most likely patch option "-p1" : `patch -p1 < 267.patch` . ..... Else see `$ patch --help` .